# How to better approach a cart design with a circular dependency

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I am using Laravel and building a shopping cart.

Consider the following:

`CartService:`

```
public function __constructor(public ShippingService $shippingService)
{}

// Various standard cart methods such as add() etc
...

protected function getItems()
{
    return $this->store->items;
}

protected function getShippingOptions()
{
    return $this->shippingService->getOptionsForCart();
}
```

`ShippingService`

```
public function __constructor(public CartService $cartService)
{}

protected function getOptionsForCart()
{
    if($this->cartService->getItems() === X){
        return ['option1', 'option2'];
    }

    return ['option2'];
}
```

This will break because there is a circular dependency. CartService relies on ShippingService and vice versa, yet it does seem logical that these would depend on each other....

I could do something like

`CartService:`

```
public function __constructor(public ShippingService $shippingService)
{}

// Various standard cart methods such as add() etc
...

protected function getItems()
{
    return $this->store->items;
}

protected function getShippingOptions()
{
    return $this->shippingService->getOptionsForCart($this);
}
```

`ShippingService`

```
public function __constructor()
{}

protected function getOptionsForCart(CartService $cartService)
{
    if($cartService->getItems() === X){
        return ['option1', 'option2'];
    }

    return ['option2'];
}
```

But this feels messy.

Is there a design pattern to deal with this particular kind of scenario?